# sending video and its audio to RTP(network) using gstreamer framework

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, h.264, rtp

I am very new to gstreamer and I want to send video and its audio from camera to RTP(network).

I am using 'AM5728' as our processor which will take video and audio as input separately, video will be compressed with H.264 in AM5728.

Now my question is 
i) how audio (associated with video) will be compressed in AM5728?

ii) how both these separately compressed video and audio are encoded and send to RTP (network), keeping audio in sync to video? We came across various plug-ins.

Is there any specific plug-in for this.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [link](https://e2e.ti.com/support/arm/sitara_arm/f/791/p/664475/2442960), which has exactly same requirement.

> i) how audio (associated with video) will be compressed in AM5728?

There is no audio encoding hardware in am5728, so you all have to do software encode, gstreamer has avenc_aac plugin for doing that.

> ii) how both these separately compressed video and audio are encoded
>   and send to RTP (network), keeping audio in sync to video? We came
>   across various plug-ins.

Following is a simple pipeline which sends audio and video to the client with ip 192.168.1.186 on port 10000 you can change ip to your convenience  and also the port:

```
 gst-launch-1.0 -vv v4l2src device=/dev/video1 io-mode=4 ! 'video/x-raw,format=(string)YUY2,width=1280,height=720,framerate=(fraction)30/1' ! vpe num-input-buffers=8 ! 'video/x-raw,format=NV12,width=1920,height=1080' !  queue ! ducatih264enc bitrate=6000 ! h264parse ! queue ! mpegts. alsasrc ! queue ! avenc_aac ! compliance=-2 ! aacparse ! mpegts.  mpegtsmux name=mpegts  ! rtpmp2tpay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.186 port=10000
```

For the receiver:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e -v udpsrc port=10000 caps="application/x-rtp\,.." ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtpmp2tdepay ! tsdemux name=demux demux. ! queue ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink demux. ! queue ! aacparse ! avdec_aac ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink
```

**Note:** you need to fill in the caps printed by the sender for udpsink0.GstPad:sink: caps in the receiver caps